# Set Listviewitem's width

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listviewitem

I have a Listview and it has one column. The view is set to List and I can see each Listviewitem but I can't select the item's row, I have to select the item's text. Is it possible to make it so that the Listviewitem's width is the same size as the Listview itself so that the user can click anywhere on the Listviewitem to select the item?

I tried searching but could only find how to change the column width and how to fix it in XAML, but this is for a WinForm.

Edit - As requested, this is the code that is generated by the Visual Studio designer. It is the only code involved with the ListviewItem.

```
System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem listViewItem1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem("1");
System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem listViewItem2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem("2");
System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem listViewItem3 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem("3");
System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem listViewItem4 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem("4");
System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem listViewItem5 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem("5");
System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem listViewItem6 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem("6");
System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem listViewItem7 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem("7");
this.listView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();

this.listView1.Activation = System.Windows.Forms.ItemActivation.OneClick;
            this.listView1.AllowDrop = true;
            this.listView1.AutoArrange = false;          
            this.listView1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
            this.listView1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.listView1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.MenuHighlight;
            this.listView1.HeaderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeaderStyle.None;
            listViewItem1.StateImageIndex = 0;
            this.listView1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem[] {
            listViewItem1,
            listViewItem2,
            listViewItem3,
            listViewItem4,
            listViewItem5,
            listViewItem6,
            listViewItem7});
            this.listView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(105, 129);
            this.listView1.Name = "listView1";
            this.listView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(157, 475);
            this.listView1.TabIndex = 4;
            this.listView1.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
            this.listView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.List;
```

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? There is no code to show, it's a standard Listview control. Can someone explain what I've done wrong in the question please so that I can fix it?

Comment: WPF or WinForms? In XAML or Code?

Comment: dans3itz, it's WinForms and code. Is there a property to set?

Comment: I don't have your code..I am not sure what you are talking about ..where is your code..?

Comment: DJ Kraze, as I mentioned in the comments of the answer you deleted, you are adjusting the Listview control itself, not the ListviewItem. Changing the column width of the Listview does not change the area you can select in the ListviewItem. These are not the same thing. I've added the only code involved with the Listview and it was automatically generated by the designer. There is no other code involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution will be using a ListBox instead of List View

In case of simple text, it is better to use ListBox.

**Update:**

Simplest hack for getting this functionality in ListView will be adding dummy spaces at the end of each item string to fill.

Comment: Unfortunately the ListBox has issues when dragging multiple items (for drag/drop functionality). ListView doesn't deselect the last item. I could extend a ListBox but since ListView does everything I need, I was hoping I could easily set the width.

Comment: Simplest hack will be adding dummy spaces at the end of each string to fill. Actually you could use custom draw or something for this.

Comment: I added an example on how he could do the custom drawing but I am not even sure the OP knows what he wants or he's having a hard time explaining it

Comment: Wolf, adding spaces would definitely solve the problem. It feels hacky, but if there are no better solutions, I'll have to use that. Thanks for the idea. (Sorry, I can't upvote with my current rep).

Comment: @DJKRAZE : He want to custom draw the items in the ListView. Not the columns.

Comment: @Moleman : You have to learn a little bit more to use custom drawing. Or you could continue with spaces... :)

Comment: He needs to do this at run-time I have provided and example of this but he obviously did not see my simple example

Comment: Wolf I will leave this one to you .. good luck getting him to understand what you are suggesting...

Comment: DJ Kraze, I understand what Wolf is suggesting. That's why I said it would definitely solve the problem. I did see your simple example and as Wolf pointed out, the columns do not need redrawing as your example showed.

Comment: I will suggest you to continue with spaces, as it will not affect your performance.

Comment: Thank you for your help Wolf, adding extra characters works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

[Better ListView](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview) and [Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express) (free) support this. It behaves like a ListBox by default (Details view, no columns):

[image]

The item auto sizing can be triggered by setting **AutoSizeItemsInDetailsView** property to **true**:

```
betterListView.AutoSizeItemsInDetailsView = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set listView1.**FullRowSelect** = true